What does convergence to a constant imply here
Let $a,b,c$ be real numbers, with $0<b_i< \infty$,
$$ \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 b_i}  \rightarrow c >0 \quad \mbox{as} \quad n \rightarrow \infty.$$
Can one find necessary conditions on $b_i$ for this to hold?
The statement is true if  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_i$ approaches a constant, but it also holds, for example, if $b_i$ oscillates between two values.
It does  not hold for $b_i=1/i$ and $a_i^2=i$.

Use the equivalence of partial sums for divergent series with equivalent general terms.

(We can assume $a_1$ is nonzero, otherwise none of the terms in the sequence are defined).
We can list necessary conditions using the following strategy: find some condition on $(b_i)_i$ which means that the above always fails, then take its negation as a necessary condition.
However, $a_1$ might be the only term of $(a_i)_i$ to be nonzero, in which case $(b_i)_{i > 1}$ can be whatever we want as long as $b_1 > 0$ (which is true by hypothesis; it's in your question).
So, answer: there aren't any necessary conditions on $(b_i)_i$ which are independent of $(a_i)_i$.

By the way, if you want to find conditions depending on $(a_i)_i$, it may help to note the following: since $x \mapsto 1/x$ is a continuous bijection on $(0, \infty)$ (our domain for $c$), the condition that
$$
\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 }{ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 b_i } \to c > 0
$$
is equivalent to
$$
\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 b_i }{ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 } \to c' > 0
$$
which is simpler to work with.

Thanks for your answer @rake, and for pointing out that at least one $a_i \ne 0$. So, given any series of $a_i$'s,  I am looking for the weakest possible conditions on $b_i$ so that my statement holds. As my examples show, requiring $\lim b_i$ to be a constant is too strong, as it misses some converging cases. Only having bounds on $b_i$ is too weak, as we can then find $a_i$'s, which gives a divergent sum.

If you're concerned about conditions being too weak as well, it sounds like you may be looking for necessary and sufficient conditions rather than just necessary conditions. It's ok if a necessary condition is too weak; it may still be necessary. (Having bounds on $b_i$ isn't necessary though, per my answer)

Yes, @rake, it is implicit in my question that the necessary conditions should also be sufficient.
